# WCF imperative binding

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

How to translate the following declarative (via configuration file) binding, to imperative binding (hardcoded inside application)?

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_IAEService">
                    <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256Sha256Rsa15" authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex"
                        requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" includeTimestamp="true" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true"
                        keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
                        messageSecurityVersion="Default" requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
                        <localClientSettings cacheCookies="true" detectReplays="true"
                            replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00"
                            replayWindow="00:05:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="10:00:00"
                            sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="true"
                            timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" cookieRenewalThresholdPercentage="60" />
                        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" issuedCookieLifetime="10:00:00"
                            maxStatefulNegotiations="128" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00"
                            negotiationTimeout="00:01:00" replayWindow="00:05:00" inactivityTimeout="00:02:00"
                            sessionKeyRenewalInterval="15:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00"
                            reconnectTransportOnFailure="true" maxPendingSessions="128"
                            maxCachedCookies="1000" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" />
                        <secureConversationBootstrap />
                    </security>
                    <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                        messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                    <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                        realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                        useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
```

Thanks

EDIT:

After Adislav's replay I tryed with:

```
    // configure security properties
    AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateDuplexBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.Default);
    security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15;
    security.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;
    security.AllowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply = true;
    security.KeyEntropyMode = SecurityKeyEntropyMode.CombinedEntropy;
    security.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;
    security.RequireSignatureConfirmation = false;

    // configure encoding properties
    TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();

    // configure transport properties
    HttpsTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();

    CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(security, encoding, transport);
```

But this code doesn't work. What do I miss?

Thanks

Comment: What exception do you receive? My example was not supposed to work as is. If you want exactly same setting you should set each property as declared in configuration (at least those which do not describe default value). For example MessageVersion in encoding element doesn't have default value and you do not set it in code.

Comment: @Ladislav MessageSecurityVersion is specified during the creation of the instance (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateDuplexBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.Default);). The error I get is a MessageSecurityException - "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail." where inner exception is "The message could not be processed because the action '' is invalid or unrecognized.". If I try with a config from config file, everything works just fine.Tnx

Comment: So that is what I mentioned in my previous comment. Message version and message security version are two different settings. Security version is set on security binding element whereas message version is set on encoding element. Your configuration defines Soap12 message version but your code do not use it so encoding element is defined with default value which is Soap12WSAddressing10.

Comment: You're the man! Setting up encoding.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12; solved the problem! Thanks a ton! Next time in Amsterdam, you have a beer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding` class and related binding elements (from the same namespace):

```
  var security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateDuplexBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.Default);
  // configure security properties
  var encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
  // configure encoding properties
  var transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
  // configure transport properties
  var customBinding = new CustomBinding(security, encoding, transport);
```

Comment: Great tip, good place where to start. Please check the questions edit, still having some problems.

Thanks